# Change Facebook page type

Tags: facebook-pages

We created a Facebook place page for our project months ago before we created our application and company. Is it possible to change the page type without losing likes, posts, comments or pictures?

We tried to create an application page and to merge the place page to it but we couldn't get the "merge" link. I suppose because page types are different.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Quoting:</sup>

> ## [How do I change my Page's category?](https://www.facebook.com/help/222732947737668/)
>
> [Different features](https://www.facebook.com/help/918592541485077/) may be available based on the category you choose.
>
> To change your Page's category:
>
> 1. Click **About** on the left side of your Page.
> 2. Below **General**, click **Edit** next to **Category**.
> 3. Type in up to 3 categories and select an option from the dropdown list that > appears.
> 4. Click **Save**.
>
> There's no limit to the number of times that you can change the category of your Page. If you don't see a category that describes your Page, choose the closest available option.

### Screenshot:

[image]